# How to use install and use network manager in debian?

Tags: debian, networking, networkmanager, qubes

I'm running Qubes with Debian 9 and therefore I have a non trivial debian installation. I tried installing `network-manager` and `network-manager-gnome` but I don't know how to launch them.

I also installed gnome settings panel. When I click in the network symbol, I get this message (after a long delay):

```
NetworkManager needs to be running
```

here's the networkmanager service:

```
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service.d
           └─30_qubes.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Sun 2019-10-13 10:29:37 -03; 22min ago
           └─ ConditionPathExists=/var/run/qubes-service/network-manager was not met
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the qubes-core-agent-networking qubes-core-agent-network-manager packages from the Qubes Debian repository.

At the minimum, I would do the following as root:

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://deb.qubes-os.org/r4.0/vm buster main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qubes.list
apt-get update
apt-get install qubes-vm-dependencies qubes-core-agent-networking qubes-core-agent-network-manager
```